# Kendo Grid cell : How to automatically trim the text to avoid the line breaking?

Tags: javascript, gridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have column with width 200 px, i cell is containing text longer than appx. 30 chars is text broken into two lines which is not looking good.

I would like to ask, how i can trim cell value to the given maximal length?
I can do it in template but it should be changed in all columns.

Is there any configuration directive for this?

Many Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is not straight-forward configuration in Kendo. You can achieve this using CSS.

You can show elipsis (...) for large text in cells :

```
.k-grid td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to show the complete cell text, you can either use Tooltips or Modal popups depending upon your requirement.